# Перезаписываются поля модели

Tags: c#, list

Собственно в list каждый раз должен записываться x,y он и записывается в дебагере видно но после в итоге получается как на скрине все элементы перезаписываются на последний

```
public class FuncLogic
{
    List<PointModel> list = new List<PointModel>();
    PointModel pm = new PointModel();
        public List<PointModel> Fx(UserDataModel data)
        {
            for (double x = data.RangeFrom; x < data.RangeTo; x += data.Step)
            {
                double y = (data.a * Math.Pow(x, 2)) + (data.b * x) + data.c;
                pm.PointX = x;
                pm.PointY = y;
                list.Add(pm);
            }
            return list;
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот модель

```
public class PointModel
    {
        public int PointId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int ChartId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double PointX
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double PointY
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сам разобрался

```
`public class FuncLogic
    {
        List<PointModel> list = new List<PointModel>();
            public List<PointModel> Fx(UserDataModel data)
            {
                for (double x = data.RangeFrom; x < data.RangeTo; x += data.Step)
                {
                    PointModel pm = new PointModel();
                    double y = (data.a * Math.Pow(x, 2)) + (data.b * x) + data.c;
                    pm.PointX = x;
                    pm.PointY = y;
                    list.Add(pm);
                }
                return list;
            }
    }`
```